# Need help to get correct sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table Employee, one of its attribute is 'Gender'. In Gender column we have two type of records 'male' or 'female'
Now i suppose to write a query which should give me an output like 1st record should be for 'Male', 2nd record for 'Female', 3rd for 'Male',
4th for 'Female'.

I have used below query to fetch record as above mentioned

```
select name, empid, salary, gender, rownum rn, case gender when 'Male' then 
    rn = (select * from (select rownum rn  from Employee) where mod (rn, 2) <> 0)
    else rn = (select * from (select rownum rn  from Employee) where mod (rn, 2) = 0) end as Org_Gender form employee;
```

but this query not able to fetch the required output.
Can someone give me the syntax please.?

Comment: `rn = ...` is invalid SQL. You can't assign variables like that. If you want assign a value to a variable you need PL/SQL and `select .. into ..`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
select empid, name, gender
from (
  select name, empid, gender,
         row_number() over (partition by gender order by name) as rn
  from employee
) t
order by rn, gender
```

`row_number() over (partition by gender ..)` will number all females from 1 to x and all males from 1 to x. By ordering the outer query using that value the final output will have the first female, then the first male, the second female, the second male and so on.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23f656/2